# Why am I getting "Document is empty" when I preview in Jasper studio book mode?

Tags: jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I use Jasper Report studio to design the report using the book template, I'm sure a single report is ok, but when I preview the merged report, I found that an empty document is returned, showing "Document is empty", the following is the code of the main page. Please help me!

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.19.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.19.1-867c00bf88cd4d784d404379d6c05e1b419e8a4c  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="healthdoc" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" whenNoDataType="AllSectionsNoDetail" sectionType="Part" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="30" bottomMargin="30" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="d2716064-8ae4-40cf-a575-33afba400e3a">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="business"/>
    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.print.create.bookmarks" value="true"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.header" value="Cover and Contents"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.book.group.cover.footer" value="Backcover"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.url" value="http://10.0.1.33:8188/jasperserver/"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.user" value="jasperadmin"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.report.resource" value="/reports/hms/hms_doc_files/main_jrxml"/>
    <property name="ireport.jasperserver.reportUnit" value="/reports/hms/hms_doc"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#FFFFFF" fontName="stsong" fontSize="50" isBold="false" pdfFontName="stsong"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#CCCCCC" fontName="stsong" fontSize="18" isBold="false" pdfFontName="stsong"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="stsong" fontSize="14" isBold="true" pdfFontName="stsong"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="stsong" pdfFontName="stsong"/>
    <parameter name="id" class="java.lang.Integer">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA[1317]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <queryString language="SQL">
        <![CDATA[select 1 FROM  mem_guest t]]>
    </queryString>
    <group name="cover">
        <groupHeader>
            <part uuid="48cb43f5-1d78-4a4e-94c7-bc80581e2049">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter" value="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE"/>
                <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                    <subreportParameter name="guestId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["cover.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </p:subreportPart>
            </part>
            <part evaluationTime="Report" uuid="bf47c82d-6bc2-422e-97e2-dfa09e013bdb">
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter" value="REPORT_DATA_SOURCE"/>
                <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
                    <subreportParameter name="guestId">
                        <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{id}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
                    </subreportParameter>
                    <subreportExpression><![CDATA["content.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
                </p:subreportPart>
            </part>
        </groupHeader>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass the connection parameter to the parts:

```
        <p:subreportPart xmlns:p="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/parts.xsd">
            <subreportParameter name="REPORT_CONNECTION">
                <subreportParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{REPORT_CONNECTION}]]></subreportParameterExpression>
            </subreportParameter>
            ...
```

Also, remove the `net.sf.jasperreports.bookmarks.data.source.parameter` property from the parts that display data from the data source, that property should only be set for Table of Contents parts.

Comment: Thanks so much, it finally showed up!